# How to modeling this relation in spring data neo4j?

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

Given I have two entity: *Person* and *Company*, and there are multiple relationships between them:

**Person - Company:**

1. The person can be the employee of the company
2. The person can be the shareholder of the company
3. The person can be the legal person of the company

**Company - Company:**

1. The company can be the legal of the company
2. The company can be the shareholder of the company

[image]

So how to modeling this in spring data neo4j?

What I tried is make 3 relationship types: EMPLOY, INVEST, LEGAL, each relationship type with the Company as the StartNode and the person as the EndNode, then in company and person, keep these relationships with the "UNDIRECTED" direction, just same as the diagram present, but always get the stackoverflow error when saving and searching.

Comment: Can you please upload your code? Your question is unclear ?

Comment: Please upload your code and try to make it as minimal as possible to reproduce the issue. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: I already described the codes in the question actually.

Comment: The question is too broad. Please share a project demonstrating the issue(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, now here is the solution in [github](https://github.com/cloudhuang/spring-data-neo4j-sample-project), all the classes are house in `sample.spring.data.neo4j` package, and the the corresponding test `sample.spring.data.neo4j.repositories.CompanyRepositoryTest`

The big issue at the beginning is it always throws the **StackOverFlow** exception which is due the the **lombok** annotation, after remove all the lombok annotations and use the plain getter/setter, everything goes well.