# spring data neo4j relationship in entity

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

Image I have the following entity: Company and Employee, with spring data neo4j annotation:

**Company.java**

```
@NodeEntity(label = "Company")
public class Company {
    /**
     * Graph ID
     */
    @GraphId
    private Long id;
    ......
}
```

**Employee.java**

```
@NodeEntity(label = "Employee")
public class Employee {
    /**
     * Graph ID
     */
    @GraphId
    private Long id;
    ......
}
```

Then there is the relationship entity for these entities:

```
@RelationshipEntity(type = "EMPLOY")
public class EmployRel {
    /**
     * Graph ID
     */
    @GraphId
    private Long id;
    @StartNode
    private Company company;
    @EndNode
    private Employee employee;
    ......
}
```

So how to keep the reference in `Company` and `Person`?

**Company.java**

```
@Relationship(type = "EMPLOY", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
private Set<EmployRel> employeeRel = new HashSet<>();
```

OR

```
@Relationship(type = "EMPLOY", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
private Set<Employee> employee = new HashSet<>();
```

**Person.java**

```
@Relationship(type = "EMPLOY", direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
private Company company = new Company();
```

OR

```
@Relationship(type = "EMPLOY", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
private EmployRel employRel = new EmployRel();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare in `Company` (outgoing relationship to `Employee` through `EmployeeRel`)

```
@Relationship
public Set<EmployRel> employees = new HashSet<>();
```

And the inverse in `Employee` :

```
@Relationship(direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
public HashSet<EmployRel> isEmployedBy = new HashSet<>();
```

Note that here you chose to have the relationship navigable on both sides, but it is not mandatory. It will also work to have it navigable only from `Company` or `Employee`.

Comment: So how about using `UNDIRECTED` in the direction?

Comment: `UNDIRECTED` is a matter of semantics. Let's say you have a `PARTNER` relationship : you don't really matter the direction, so you can use `UNDIRECTED` in that case. It will work the same as a directed relationship.

Comment: Thanks, I know this direction semantics, for my case, maybe you need to read my another question indeed, please see  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46503104/how-to-modeling-this-relation-in-spring-data-neo4j, in this question, the company can be the "Investor" and "Investee", so will have the Company -[:INVESTMENT]- Company relationship, this is really the boring things to me.

Comment: I posted a comment there